# SQL Inner Join for calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to set sales year to date to automatically equal the sum of invoice headers where the account codes equal.

```
ALTER TABLE DEBTORS_MASTER  
    ALTER COLUMN Sales_Year_To_Date AS 
          (SELECT SUM (INVOICE_HEADER.Total_Sell_Amount_Excl_VAT)
           FROM DEBTORS_MASTER
           INNER JOIN DEBTORS_MASTER ON INVOICE_HEADER.Account_Code = DEBTORS_MASTER.ACCOUNT_CODE);
```

I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: If you need to `update` value(s) in column `Sales_Year_To_Date`, why are you using `alter`? or am i getting it wrong? Whats the question? Do you need default value for column `Sales_Year_To_Date` on `insert`?

Comment: Can you show your table structure along with some data?

Comment: @zarruq i want to have Sales_Year_To_Date to automatically equal the sum from the different table, not an update. My sql statement is working.

Comment: @dylmatthews: You mean on every insert, the `Sales_Year_To_Date` be populated automatically with  `max` of %sell_amount%?

Comment: Computed columns cannot reference other rows, even from their own table. Have you considered placing this total in an *indexed view*, if it even makes sense to store this total?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it seperately

Alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE DEBTORS_MASTER
ALTER COLUMN Sales_Year_To_Date INT
```

Update statement

```
UPDATE t1
SET Sales_Year_To_Date = Sales_Year_To_Date
FROM DEBTORS_MASTER t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(INVOICE_HEADER.Total_Sell_Amount_Excl_VAT) AS Sales_Year_To_Date
    FROM DEBTORS_MASTER
    INNER JOIN DEBTORS_MASTER ON INVOICE_HEADER.Account_Code = DEBTORS_MASTER.ACCOUNT_CODE
    ) t2 ON t2.ACCOUNT_CODE = t1.ACCOUNT_CODE
```

Comment: The problem with storing this calculated value (and it not being a computed column or indexed view) is that, *as soon as the `UPDATE` has finished running*, the data may be out of date. That's why we usually recommend *not* to store data that can be computed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
UPDATE DM
SET Sales_Year_To_Date = IH.sumAmount
FROM DEBTORS_MASTER AS DM
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Account_Code, SUM(Total_Sell_Amount_Excl_VAT) sumAmount
        FROM INVOICE_HEADER
        GROUP BY Account_Code
    ) IH
ON IH.Account_Code = DM.Account_Code
```

Comment: The problem with storing this calculated value (and it not being a computed column or indexed view) is that, *as soon as the `UPDATE` has finished running*, the data may be out of date. That's why we usually recommend *not* to store data that can be computed.